# Replacing numbers in a pdf with IText7 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I am creating a PDF and in the first page there is the indication of the number of pages that exist.
Only after rendering all the content do I know the total number of pages.

The final step is replacing the text in the firt page with the total number of pages but I am facing a problem because I can replace text without any problem, but not numbers.

This is my code:

```cs
        public byte[] AddTotalPageNumber(byte[] document)
        {
            using (var _pdfReader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(document)))
            using (var _stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var _pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(_stream))
            using (var _pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(_pdfReader, _pdfWriter))
            {

                var coverPage = _pdfDocument.GetFirstPage();
                var dict = coverPage.GetPdfObject();
                var obj = dict.Get(PdfName.Contents);

                if (obj.GetType() == typeof(PdfStream))
                {
                    PdfStream stream = (PdfStream)obj;
                    byte[] data = stream.GetBytes(true);
                    var stringData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(data).Replace("NUM", "S19", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
                    stream.SetData(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(stringData));
                }

                _pdfDocument.Close();

                return _stream.ToArray();
            }            
        }
```

Only the S in the replace string is shown in the final PDF.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This manner of content editing is always a gamble. I would propose a different approach, e.g. using page events or form fields or simply remembering the position aft which you want to draw the total page number.

Comment: I ended up by editing the document after it had all the pages and added a paragraph with the text with the total number of pages.